# Transform UL->li inot List selected for isotope filtering menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, jquery-isotope

I have a problem with my isotope filters menu.
I would like to transform the simple links in a selected list box but I have problems with the JS or I don't really know if it's possible with the Ul->Li.

Here is the menu select

```js
jQuery(function ($) {
 
 var $container = $('#posts-list');
 $container.isotope({
  itemSelector : '.item', 
    layoutMode : 'masonry'
 });
 
 var $optionSets = $('#filters'),
 $optionLinks = $optionSets.find('a');
 
 $optionLinks.click(function(){
 var $this = $(this);
 if ( $this.hasClass('selected') ) {
   return false;
 }
 var $optionSet = $this.parents('#filters');
 $optionSets.find('.selected').removeClass('selected');
 $this.addClass('selected');
 
  var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
 $container.isotope({ filter: selector });
 
 return false;
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="filters">
    <li><a href="#" data-filter="*" id="all">Everything</a></li>
 <?php 
  $terms = get_terms("category");
  $count = count($terms);
  if ( $count > 0 ){
   foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    echo "<li><a href='#' data-filter='.".$term->slug."'>" . $term->name . "</a></li>\n";
   }
  } 
 ?>
</ul>

///////////////////
DISPLAY ITEMS
///////////////////

<div id="posts-list">
    <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); 
   $termsArray = get_the_terms( $post->ID, "category" );
   $termsString = "";
   foreach ( $termsArray as $term ) {
    $termsString .= $term->slug.' ';
   } ?> 
   <div class="<?php echo $termsString; ?> item bit-3">
               // DISPLAY THE CONTENT
   </div>
    <?php endwhile;  ?>
   </div>
```

And I tried for the selected menu:

```js
jQuery(function ($) {
 
 var $container = $('#posts-list');
 $container.isotope({
  itemSelector : '.item', 
    layoutMode : 'masonry'
 });
  
$("#filters").on("click", ".init", function() {
    $(this).closest("ul").children('li:not(.init)').toggle();
});

var allOptions = $("ul").children('li:not(.init)');
$("ul").on("click", "li:not(.init)", function() {
    allOptions.removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    $("ul").children('.init').html($(this).html());
    allOptions.toggle();
});

  });
```

```html
<ul id="filters">
    <li class="init"><a href="#" data-filter="*" id="all">Everything</a></li>
 <?php 
  $terms = get_terms("category");
  $count = count($terms);
  if ( $count > 0 ){
   foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    echo "<li><a href='#' data-filter='.".$term->slug."'>" . $term->name . "</a></li>\n";
   }
  } 
 ?>
</ul>
```

Could you help me please?

Comment: I did not get you ...What is the error or what do you want to achieve ?

Comment: The Javascript doesn't want to filter the isotope box. I would like to use a <select> Tag or a <ul><li> Tag like my code looking like a select tag. Like here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select Thanks for help

Comment: Why are you making <ul> <li> ?? Simply list your category in <select><option> ..

Comment: I tried using this: https://jsfiddle.net/02o7ayrw/ But The filters doesn't work. I don't know why cause in the JS I don't select any <ul> or <li>, just by the ids ...

Comment: It's not online, but here is a Jsfeedle of the complete code: https://jsfiddle.net/h1kdoo2c/ Thanks

Comment: Give me the link of the isotope so that I can make small demo of it in my machine.

Comment: Here is the isotope script i'm using: https://jsfiddle.net/vbv5eeqv/ Thankyou!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code will do it :

**PHP** :

```
<select id="filters">
     <option data-filter="*" id="all">Everything</option>
    <?php 
        $terms = get_terms("category");
        $count = count($terms);
        if ( $count > 0 ){
            foreach ( $terms as $term ) { 
                echo "<option data-filter='.".$term->slug."'>" . $term->name . "
                         </option>\n";
            }
        } 
    ?>
</select>

<?php $the_query = new WP_Query( 'posts_per_page=50' );
    if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
    <div id="posts-list">
    <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); 
           $termsArray = get_the_terms( $post->ID, "category" ); ?> 
          <!-- Get the terms for this particular item -->
    <?php 
        $termsString = "";
        foreach ( $termsArray as $term ) {
            $termsString .= $term->slug.' ';
        } ?> 
    <div class="<?php echo $termsString; ?>item">
        <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
            <h1>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
                    <?php the_title(); ?>
                </a>
            </h1>
            <section class="post_content">
                <p><?php echo get_the_content(); ?></p>
            </section>
        </article>
    </div> <!-- end item -->
    <?php endwhile;  ?>
</div> <!-- end isotope-list -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

**JS** :

```
jQuery(function ($) {

    var $container = $('#posts-list'),
    filters = {};

    $container.isotope({
        itemSelector : '.item'
    });

    // filter buttons
    $('select').change(function(){
        var $this = $(this);

        var group = $this.attr('data-filter');

        filters[ group ] = $this.find(':selected').attr('data-filter');

        var isoFilters = [];
        for ( var prop in filters ) {
            isoFilters.push( filters[ prop ] )
        }

        var selector = isoFilters.join('');
        $container.isotope({ filter: selector });
        return false;
    });

});
```

**NOTE:** Tested

Comment: Ok Rohil_PHPBeginner, thank you very much, it works better!! Thanks